Clang-format: prefer declaration alignment over keeping declaration on a single Line
I'm using clang-format to format my C code, and I've hit a behavior I can't figure out how to reconfigure. Take this example code:
void        short_function1(int argument1);
void        short_function2(int argument1);
void long_function(int argument1, int argument2, int argument3, int argument4);

In this example, even though I enable AlignConsecutiveDeclarations, long_function does not align with the first two short functions because doing so would cause it to go over the character limit. However, I have set BinPackArguments: false, and what I'd like is for clang-format to prefer breaking the function arguments over not aligning function declarations. In my example, that'd look something like this:
void        short_function1(int argument1);
void        short_function2(int argument1);
void        long_function(int argument1, 
                          int argument2, 
                          int argument3, 
                          int argument4);

I've tried messing with the Penalty settings but to no avail. Here's my .clang-format for reference:
BasedOnStyle: LLVM

AllowAllArgumentsOnNextLine:      false
BinPackArguments:                 false
BinPackParameters:                false
BreakBeforeBraces:                Stroustrup
BreakBeforeBinaryOperators:       All
BreakInheritanceList:             AfterComma
BreakTemplateDeclarations:        Yes

AlignAfterOpenBracket:                      Align
AllowAllParametersOfDeclarationOnNextLine:  false

AlignConsecutiveAssignments:          AcrossEmptyLines
AlignConsecutiveDeclarations:         AcrossEmptyLines
AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine:  AllIfsAndElse
AllowShortLoopsOnASingleLine:         true
AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine:     false

